# Programmatically get GPU information on Android without using GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I need to get GPU information (including vendor, renderer, version, available extensions etc) programmatically in my Android SDK. So far, I know these ways to do this.

1. Run `dumpsys | grep GLES command` (Does not work because `dumpsys` is a system-level command available only to some system apps or the ADB shell)
2. Create a `GLSurfaceView`, attach a `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, and get GPU information in its callback (Works fine but I want to know if there is a way to do that without creating a `GLSurfaceView` since I do not want to tinker with the host app's view hierarchy from my SDK)

Comment: Can you create a `GLSurfaceView` using [its constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView?hl=en#GLSurfaceView(android.content.Context)) and simply not attach it to a view hierarchy?

Comment: Without attaching it to view hierarchy, it is not possible to get the GPU information in the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) project.

Within it there is `GLESInfoActivity`, which demonstrates how to obtain the information you're looking for.

The function `gatherGlInfo()` has the code you need and it states that:

> We need a GL context to examine, which means we need an EGL surface. Create a 1x1 pbuffer.

This `EGLSurface` is required to obtain the information from the `GLES20` class (OpenGLES information). You do not need this surface if you just want the information from the `EGL14` class (EGL information). However, given your question you will need information from the `GLES20` class and thus require an `EGLSurface`.

In your case it should suffice to copy this method and use an offscreen surface, which would avoid the need to use `GLSurfaceView`.

You will also need some of the code within the `gles` package for the `EGL` set up and configuration. In particular:

- EglCore
- EglSurfaceBase
- OffscreenSurface